# re assign same function on element?

Tags: javascript

i have assigned a function outside of its scope like this:

```
toggleEdit.setAttribute('onclick', `toggleEdit('${dataId}')`);
```

inside the toggle edit function i want to refer to it again, but it's not happening

```
function toggleEdit(dataId) {
  ....
  saveEdit.onclick = () => { // this is same element as toggleEdit above, function changed
    if (newText) {
      ...
      saveEdit.setAttribute('onclick', `toggleEdit('${dataId}')`); // refer again like above
    } else {
      alert('Please enter a valid todo')
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

saveEdit is same element as toggleEdit above but reassigning when condition is met not working. help?

Comment: A comment about code style: try to be more consistent (why are you using both `setAttribute()` and `.onclick` to set a click handler?) and avoid reusing variable names (why is `toggleEdit` both a reference to an DOM element and a function?).

Comment: i am sorry for having difficulty explaining, but i hope i am understandable, I am trying to introduce myself in dom and pure js, just discovered those method along so i will be changing that after i got it all working

Comment: We don't have enough information to offer suggestions. What are `dataId` and `newText`? What does the html element look like that you are listening for clicks on? Please show more code.